# values are not posting into Nodejs API in Angular

Tags: angular

I am **trying to send two values into my Nodejs API i.e. userId and username** using Angular but it is not working neither giving any kind off error, only it says value `'userId' is declared but its value is never read`

API is working fine in Postman so no issues in api, I think there is something into my below code.

```
 inseruserdata( userId: string,username: string){
 this.article.deletelog({ username: this.username,userId:this.userId}).subscribe(data => {
console.log(this.userId, this.username);

    })
  }
```

Here is my complete code -

```
import { Component, OnInit,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { ArticleService } from 'src/app/article.service';
import { IArticle } from 'src/app/models/pub.model';
import { forkJoin } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-deletearticle',
  templateUrl: './deletearticle.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./deletearticle.component.css'],

})


export class DeletearticleComponent implements OnInit {
  @ViewChild('closebutton') closebutton;
  articleDetails: IArticle;
  reason: string="";
  showModal: boolean;
  userId: string;
  username: string;
  myDate = new Date();
  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private article: ArticleService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let date: Date = new Date();
    this.userId = localStorage.getItem('userid')
    this.username = localStorage.getItem('username')

    this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      let { id } = params

      this.article
        .getArticlesData({ articleid: id })
        .subscribe((data: any) => {
          this.articleDetails = data.result[0];
          console.log(this.articleDetails);
        });
    })
    console.log(this.userId, this.username);
  }
 

      insertuserdata(){
        this.article.deletelog({ username: this.username,userId:this.userId}).subscribe(data => {
       console.log(data);
        console.log(this.userId, this.username);
        console.log("hiii");

        })
      }
```

**service**

```
  deletelog(payload) {
return this.http.post(environment.api_url + '/articles/articlesById', payload)
  }
```

Even I console the value to check if value can accessible or not and it is accessible in function

Comment: Your method accepts two arguments that it never uses, because throughout its body you use `this` to get the variables from the parent class.

Comment: @WillAlexander i have updatd the code with full info

Comment: Can you also share your service method? Do you see a network call being made?

Comment: @WillAlexander network is not being called also, I have shared service ,method

Comment: If no network call is being made, then your subscription to your service method isn't happening. Are you using HttpClient in your service? Have you imported HttpClientModule in your feature module/AppModule? With the code you have shown here, there doesn't appear to be anything wrong. Are you sure nothing happens in the network tab of Dev tools?